# How do I pass a closure as a parameter in swift (just the basics)

Tags: xcode, swift

So, I just started learning swift yesterday, so bear with me.
I'm working on closures. I have a very simple set of statements.

---

```
    let myClosure = {
        println("this is a simple test")
    }

    func showWork( closure : ()->() ) {
      closure()
    }

showWork(myClosure)
```

---

I know that I am doing something wrong because println isn't working in the xCode playground. Basically, I've created a simple closure and passed it to my function. But, println isn't printing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tried it via Playground?

Comment: I guess so: hover over the grey part right and click the circle that will appear at some place. That opens a new output window. Also try restarting XCode and issue: `rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"`

Comment: Your code is fine. To view println() output, open the Assistant Editor via the menu: View > Assistant Editor > View Assistant Editor or the shortcut combination ⌥⌘⏎

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `() -> ()` write `Void -> Void`. So the whole thing would look like this:

```
let myClosure = {
    print("this is a simple test")
}

func showWork( closure : Void->Void ) {
    closure()
}

showWork(myClosure)
```